# Java convert character stream into human "readable" String

Tags: java, encoding, groovy, character-encoding, utf8-decode

I have a bunch of characters with that looks something like this:

```
&#1050;&#1086;&#1084;&#1091;&#1085;&#1080;&#1082;&#1072;&#1094;&#1080;&#1086;&#1085;&#1085;&#1072; &#1082;&#1072;&#1073;&#1077;&#1083;&#1085;&#1072; &#1089;&#1080;&#1089;&#1090;&#1077;&#1084;&#1072;
```

and sometimes I have a mix like this:

```
G&#233;n&#233;ralit&#233;s
```

The first translates into :

**Комуникационна кабелна система**

and the second to:

**Généralités**

I can see this using a browser and place them into the body.

But how can I make java output the "real" characters ? What is the above encoding called?

I have tried a couple of things, and lastly this ( which did not work ):

```
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(); lst.add("&#1050;"); lst.add("&#1086;");
for ( String s : lst ) {

    Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap( s.getBytes() );

    // decode UTF-8
    CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);

    // encode ISO-8559-1
    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = iso88591charset.encode(data);
    byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();

    System.out.println ( new String(outputData) )
}
```

Comment: those are called entities. if you look for entity-to-unicode conversion you may find what you're looking for that way

Comment: @dldnh thanks for clarifying ! not the easiest thing to search the web for :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) to unescape this sort of thing.  In Groovy:

```
@Grab( 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' )
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils as SEU

def str = 'G&#233;n&#233;ralit&#233;s'

println SEU.unescapeHtml( str )
```